# Iteration of BLOB query on R issues with iterating the list

Tags: r, binary

I asked this question in the wrong way, so I am back to see if I can get it straight. Queried a local mariaDB instance for for variables on tens of thousands of lines of data. One of the objects was stored as a LONGBLOB and so the returned tibble has three character vectors and one is a list of raw binaries. Code is as follows.

The LONGBLOB data is XML data with forms that contain legislative language and data on the legislature.

```
cal_query<-dbGetQuery(conn = con,
                       statement = "SELECT bill_version_tbl.subject, bill_version_tbl.bill_version_id, bill_history_tbl.end_status, bill_version_tbl.bill_xml
                                      FROM bill_history_tbl
                                      JOIN bill_version_tbl ON bill_history_tbl.bill_id = bill_version_tbl.bill_id
                                    WHERE bill_history_tbl.end_status = 'Passed' || 'passed'
                                      && bill_version_tbl.bill_version_action_date >= 2001
                                      && bill_version_tbl.bill_xml!= 'NULL'
                                    LIMIT 0, 55000;") %>%
  as_tibble()

cal_query$bill_xml<-unlist(cal_query$bill_xml)## this is where I was hoping to enlist and it did not work properly (Error: Assigned data `unlist(cal_query$bill_xml)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 55000 rows.
x Assigned data has 1932739308 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.)

for(i in seq_along(cal_query$bill_xml)){
  cal_query$bill_xml[[i]] <- readBin(cal_query$bill_xml[[i]], character(), endian = "little")
}
```

I tried to run the for loop before the enlist function, but it also returned an error which led me to believe it needed to be unlisted to get the iteration to work. But when I did the for loop first I ran into the issue of having only the first four rows of the list to come back out of their binary format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precedence:

```
a || b && c
```

is the same as

```
a || (b && c)
```

but you probably wanted

```
(a || b) && c
```

Also, if you want case folding, use a suitable `COLLATION`.  Then you won't need to test for both "Passed" and "passed".

Oops, it is actually worse than that...

```
 WHERE bill_history_tbl.end_status = 'Passed' || 'passed'
    && bill_version_tbl.bill_version_action_date >= 2001
    && bill_version_tbl.bill_xml!= 'NULL'
```

means

```
 WHERE bill_history_tbl.end_status = 'Passed'
    OR ('passed'
   AND bill_version_tbl.bill_version_action_date >= 2001
   AND bill_version_tbl.bill_xml!= 'NULL')
```

`'passed'` by its lonesome evaluates to `FALSE`.  That cancels out the tests after it.  So, it is down to

```
 WHERE bill_history_tbl.end_status = 'Passed'
    OR (FALSE)
```

The `OR FALSE` can be tossed leaving only

```
 WHERE bill_history_tbl.end_status = 'Passed'
```

Change your query to:

```
 WHERE ( bill_history_tbl.end_status = 'Passed'
      OR bill_history_tbl.end_status = 'passed' )
   AND bill_version_tbl.bill_version_action_date >= 2001
   AND bill_version_tbl.bill_xml!= 'NULL'
```

Wait, there is another issue -- maybe:

```
AND bill_version_tbl.bill_xml!= 'NULL'
```

Are you testing against the 4 letters `"NULL"` or checking for the column being `NULL`?  It's OK in the first case, but in the second case, you must say:

```
AND bill_version_tbl.bill_xml  IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I am not even going to lie to you, that looks foreign to me. I am a Political Sci guy by trade and I was working with a peer who said they could handle scraping data for me and they gave me nonsense and couldn't get the job done. I had to take an impromptu MySQL class on udemy and also just began using R as opposed to STATA only 8 months ago. I am doing my best, but could you explain how I would make those statements up above?

Comment: @joloppyu9 - I added to my Answer.  Do you have more queries that need checking?

Comment: Thank you my friend, that did exactly what I needed. Thing is I ended up going a different direction anyways. In any case, this helped me with best practices for querying which I am sure I will need for other things in this database. So thanks! Accepting now!